# Convert rdb to an ontology

Tags: ms-access, relational-database, ontology

I have a Microsoft Access relational database which I am trying to convert into an ontology for Activity Based Intelligence purposes.  I am new to ontologies and was wondering how this would be done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Learn about ontologies, then have at it. 
http://doc.utwente.nl/50826/1/thesis_Guizzardi.pdf